# appengine: Delete source files?

Tags: python, file, google-app-engine, delete-file

I am fooling with Google App Engine again and I deployed my source to the live app, but I neglected to delete some local files that were unrelated.   Anyway, I found a way update or download sources using appcfg.py.  But I can't find a way to actually delete source code off of the live service.  Is that allowed?  I would like to delete those unrelated files.

Thanks for any info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should deploy a new version that does not contain those files, then using the [appspot admin console](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/) set that as the default version and delete the old version.